# Connection faliure issue when i hit the web API in Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Some time i am facing issue of `Connect Failure` when I hit the web api in Xamarin IOS project. API is working fine and issue is in connection. If any one have an idea to solve this issue or have a link through which i can solve this issue. 
please send me because i have tried many solution but couldn't solve it.

[image]

**Error Log** ::::::::::::::::

> {System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Too many open files) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Too many open files
>     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor (AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType) [0x00060] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:214 
>     at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x000f6] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:189 
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00065] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:946 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2 endFunction, System.Action`1 endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) <0x1002da730 + 0x0005b> in :0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:199 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x10027a4f0 + 0x0001b> in <filename unknown>:0 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x003d6] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/9.6.1.9/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:372 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:199 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x10027a4f0 + 0x0001b> in :0 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000a9] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/9.6.1.9/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:274 
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2168 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].GetResultCore (Boolean waitCompletionNotification) <0x1002d9dc0 + 0x0006f> in <filename unknown>:0 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].get_Result () <0x1002d9d50 + 0x0002b> in :0 
>     at RSystemApp.Controller.HolidayController.GetLeaveInformation (Int64 employeeId) [0x00025] in D:\Mukesh\TFSCode\RSIMobileApp\RSystemApp\RSystemApp\Controller\HolidayController.cs:83 
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Too many open files) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Too many open files
>     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor (AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType) [0x00060] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:214 
>     at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x000f6] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:189 
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00065] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:946 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2 endFunction, System.Action`1 endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) <0x1002da730 + 0x0005b> in :0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:199 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x10027a4f0 + 0x0001b> in <filename unknown>:0 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x003d6] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/9.6.1.9/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:372 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:199 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x10027a4f0 + 0x0001b> in :0 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000a9] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/9.6.1.9/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:274 <---
>   }

Comment: What does your webapi do?

Comment: API gives the records of Leave. API is working fine i checked many time. May be the issue is in connection. I am also using the maximum buffer size.

Comment: Are there large records returning from the api?

Comment: Since you did not post any code of the problem area, so blindly I would have to say your HttpWebRequest objects are not being disposed... but that is a pure shot in the dark... Since you are running out of file descriptors I would start by making sure that you using "using blocks" and that you are not in some fault/retry loop that is recreating your web requests over and over

Comment: @Akash Amin  API is returning small records

Comment: @Sushil You mean if when i will be dispose the object of HttpWebRequest after hitting the API then it will work fine ..... (:

Comment: @SushiHangover I have disposed the HttpWebRequest object after hitting the API but issue is not solve. It's coming again and again after disposing the object

Comment: Did you check if your execution is going into a fault/retry loop?

Comment: Yes i checked ....

Comment: do you use SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

How often do you call web API?

I have this problem before.

My code：

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient ();
...
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync (“webapi url” , postContent);
```

Solution：

```
using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient ())
{
   ...
   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("webapi url" , postContent);
   ...
}
```

It seems like you don't dispose HttpClient

You can see this page:
https://dotblogs.com.tw/rainmaker/2016/06/06/103035

Hope you can fix it